# Import Excel Spread Sheet into Access - Format Issue with [h]:mm:ss

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I need to import an Excel spread sheet into Microsoft Access. I have a column which is in the format [h]:mm:ss. When I import it with Access I have specified the column to be in Date/Time format but it displays incorrectly.

For example in Excel it would show 452:32:00 but in Access it would show 18/01/1900 20:32:00. I need to write a query in Access to display this in the same format it is shown in Excel.

I'd appreciate if someone could show me the SQL to do this. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried importing it as text instead of date/time? (Unless you want to have the datatype as date/time.)

Comment: I need to multiply the value by a vale from another column in Access. I won' be able to do this in text format but I didn't wish to complicate the question too much.

Comment: That's okay. I'm not sure that Access can have this formatting, but let's wait and see if someone's got some magic trick :)

Comment: Is it possible to do the multiplaction first (simply multiple by 2 for example) and then get the total hours, minutes, seconds (452, 32, 0 in my example) from the imported date/time and display it in text in the form hours:minutes:seconds?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you here... :s

Comment: Well ignore the multiplication part for now. Is it possible to retrieve the total hours (452) from the imported date/time (18/01/1900 20:32:00). That way I could do the same with the minutes and seconds and concatenate the information to display as text.

Comment: I think that it would be easier if you pick "Text" in the Excel Import Wizard, you should be getting `452:32:00`. I just tested it on my MS Access 2007 and it worked. Otherwise, I'm not too familiar with converting back the date into its constituent hours, minutes and seconds. The `HOUR()` function doesn't consider the days, which means the SQL query will be quite long if you have large values of hours to account for the months and years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update 1:* a new approach to storing durations--store everything in seconds, instead of three separate columns for hours, minutes and seconds. Access' `double` type allows us to store durations in the scale of geological ages.

Steps:

1. Import spreadsheet into an Access table of durations--say, `tblDurations`.
2. Perform arithmetic operations on the durations, e.g. add (the corresponding columns in) two rows together, multiple a row by 2, sum all the rows, etc.
3. Format and display the output.

Below, I'll be using mostly Access's ANSI-92 SQL syntax which works through the DAO `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` method. You'll have to use DAO for best results here instead of the Access GUI query editor(s). Let me know if you need any clarification on this.

## Import Spreadsheet

### Create Table

```
create table tblDurations (
  ID autoincrement primary key
, durSeconds double not null
)
```

### Import Durations

I like to import data from a simple CSV file. I'll show you that approach here. Say you have a CSV file `durations.csv` that looks like this in Excel:

```
Duration
01:59:59
02:01:57
00:00:04
```

You can run the following to import it:

```
insert into tblDurations (durSeconds)
select
  hour(Duration) * 60 * 60
+ minute(Duration) * 60
+ second(Duration)
from [Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\Users\YourName\Documents;].[durations.csv]
```

Note that in the last line above you substitute your own file path and name.

## Arithmetic on Durations

Now you can switch to Access' GUI SQL editor. Let's say we want to multiply a certain duration by 2.5:

```
select
  2.5 as multiplier
, multiplier * durSeconds as s
from tblDurations
where ID = 1
```

## Format and Display Output

The trick here is to convert a duration expressed in seconds into hours, minutes and seconds:

```
select
  int(sq.s / (60 * 60)) as Hours
, int((sq.s - Hours * 60 * 60) / 60) as Minutes
, sq.s - Hours * 60 * 60 - Minutes * 60 as Seconds
from (
  select
    2.5 as multiplier
  , multiplier * durSeconds as s
  from tblDurations
  where ID = 1
) as sq
```

Finally, you format the output hours, minutes and seconds as `hh:mm:ss`, which I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. Appreciate the depth you've gone into.

Comment: @nfplee no worries--in fact I realised that it's easier to store everything in seconds--see above!