# How to get sum of working hour

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wants to add two or more figures of Working Hour in Access 2007 Query Ex,
i have three records like

```
1:30
5:18
10:52
```

I want to get sum of these records in Access query..i use `SUM` function for it but it returns false value.

Comment: Can you show your column names and the query that you tried?

Comment: yaah i use function as  `(left(wrk,instrsub(wrk,":")*60)+(right(wrk,instrrev(wrk,":")))` but can't succeed             Here `wrk` is column name.

Comment: In your data sample, there is just one column?  It is a time value?  You want it summed?

Comment: yaah.. i just want to sum ..

Comment: Instead of storing times as time values, you are better off storing durations in seconds using the `double` data type. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18303594/20371

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql so try this,

```
create table #temp(Tm time)
insert into #temp values ( CAST('1:30' as time))
insert into #temp values (CAST('5:18' as time))

insert into #temp values (CAST('10:52' as time))
select * from #temp select cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), Tm))/60 as nvarchar(3)) + ':' + cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), Tm))%60 as varchar(2))  from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
format(sum([HOURSfield]),"hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting false values, the point is that the values are formatted as Date, and not Hour/Minutes.

I've been through this before, and couldn't figure a simple and clean way to code with SQL only.

**The good news is that someone already had solved this using VBA:**

1. Click Alt+F11 to open Visual Basic for Applications
2. Click in Insert -> Module
3. Paste the code you'll found in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30543581/8195723
4. Use the function FormatHourMinute() in your SQL code, so it will present the desired format.

> FormatHourMinute(Sum(tbl_activites.working_hours)) As Wk_Hour

NOTE: The values returned by this function are String type. You will be not able to